# Sticky navbar is bouncing

Tags: navbar, sticky, bounce

http://testsites.wz.cz/

```js
(function($) {
  //SCROLL
  var menu = $(".menu"),
    menuLinks = menu.find("a");

  menuLinks.on("click", function(event) {
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  //BACK-TO-TOP
  var backToTop = $("<a>", {
    href: "#cover",
    class: "back-to-top",
    html: '<i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-5x"></i>'
  });

  backToTop
    .hide()
    .appendTo("body")
    .on("click", function() {
      $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    });

  var win = $(window);
  win.on("scroll", function() {
    if (win.scrollTop() >= 600) backToTop.fadeIn();
    else backToTop.fadeOut();
  });
  //STICKY MENU
  $(document).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("nav").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
      $(".decor").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
      $(".logo").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
    } else {
      $("nav").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
      $(".decor").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
      $(".logo").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Hi I´m new here :)

I found many tuts for sticky navbar it is good looking but it has one problem. It is bouncing while changing height(padding). When at home click other section. When at other sections click home. IDK where is problem.

THX.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a jquery class change, take a look in your script.

Change

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top large">
```

To :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top small">
```

Final answer, change this in your CSS :

```
    nav.small li a {
    padding: 25px 0;
    transition: all  1s;
    }
```

Another way :

```
    nav.small:AFTER li a {
    padding: 16px 0;
    transition: all  1s;
    }

    nav.large:AFTER li a {
    padding: 25px 0;
    transition: all  1s;
    }
```

Comment: I added script.js on top cuz I don´t understand u correctly.

Comment: Look in your script after //sticky menu, you are removing and adding a class to your navbar. In your file style.css there is 16 px for small and 26 px for large...

Comment: Where is your problem exactly, you dont want the height to be modified or you dont want the page to scroll?

Comment: no scrolling is fine. Problem starts when you click on menu items when resizing navbar. It bounce.

Comment: Ahhh okay, i think its due to the padding of your li in CSS change to 25px for both and it wont bounce...

Comment: But lower padding is for centering li items in nav bar verticaly. I try to record the problem :/

Comment: Try watch this gifs and look on LI elements. http://imgur.com/2XrIyaI                 http://imgur.com/dHSQYCo

Comment: Well use the pseudo class AFTER instead then, that should do the trick.

Comment: Does it work now? Could you vote my answer if it does?

Comment: I am sorry but not :/ look